# Word пишет, что после слова "шагом" нужна запятая. Видимо, программа ошибается?

Tags: пунктуация

Быстрым шагом дойдя до окраин, остановил проходящую маршрутку и вернулся в столицу острова.

Comment: То что точки нет, Word пишет?

Comment: Зачем вообще етого Ворда слушаться?! Он же не Розенталь. Его задача - ***указать** проблемное место*.

Answer (score 5):

Ошибается. Автоматические программы проверки правописания не очень сильны в пунктуации. Word cумел обнаружить деепричастный оборот, но не увидел, что "быстрым шагом" тоже в него входит.